# Fragment Activity and List Adapter Null Pointer Exception Error

Tags: android-activity, fragment, listadapter

I created listview and fragment activity.But List Adapter not working.
Fragment Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainFeed.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```

Activity Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
```

List Adapter Code:

```
public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}
```

List Adapter is null.

Please help me.

Comment: welcome at stackoverflow.
 please add some items in `feedItems`. Your code look like you set empty(null) `feedItems` in `FeedListAdapter` so you get _List Adapter null._

Answer (score 0):

Try changing FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List feedItems) for FeedListAdapter(Context cntx, List feedItems) i think you are sending the Context and trying to get the Activity in the constructor...